# What is wrong with security.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement Oauth 2 using client credentials.I successfully get the access token.
but when i use that access token to call the web service i get 403.
Can yo please suggest what am i doing wrong.`

```
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
        parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- Protected resources -->
<http pattern="/employee/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/employee/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Authentication in config file -->
<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- Token Store -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <!-- VIV -->
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<!-- Token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="dstest" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<!-- Client Definition -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client" secret="12345"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" redirect-uri="https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
        scope="read,write,trust" access-token-validity="3000"
        refresh-token-validity="600" />

</oauth:client-details-service>


<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>
<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

`

Comment: did you start from a working example from the internet? what's the diff between the working file and yours?

Comment: Please add Spring Security logs with `DEBUG` enabled to your question.

Comment: the only  change i have added is in authorized-grant-types.
I wan to access the web service using client credentials therefore i have added client_credentials in authorized-grant-types